# How can real time comments be turned on?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

A few months ago comments were loading automatically, now I have to refresh to see new ones. How do I turn auto-load back on?

Comment: Comments to my posts are still loading automatically, but posts from my friends don't appear in my timeline until I hit refresh.  Are you asking about comments or posts?

Comment: Comments to my posts or to someone else's post to which I'm receiving notifications. It used to be as fast as the chat but now it doesn't load anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved itself a day after I used the "report a problem" form under options. They didn't answer me but it's quite a coincidence for this feature to suddenly start working after so many months.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably experiencing is a page with a lot of traffic—they don't autoload because that would be too server intensive, but comments you leave on your actual friends’ pages should autoload no problem.

Comment: It also happens in a private group with fewer than 200 members.

Answer (score -1):

The browser is not the cause of this issue. It might be your browser cache or internet connection speed.
Try clearing your browser cache and cookies.

Comment: I just tested Facebook in Chrome's Incognito Mode but it didn't update in real time.